# How to get a list of YouTube channel emojis?

Tags: youtube, youtube-livestreaming-api

I want to get a list of emojis from youtube live chat (urls or images). For example emojis from [this channel](https://youtu.be/5qap5aO4i9A).  Is there a way to get them using youtube livestreaming api?

[image: channel emoji list]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if those emojis are available through any API, but, one way you can get those emojis are:

- Click on any of the channel emoji list.
- A new window will appear "for join to that channel".
- Right-click on any of the emojis from the channel > inspect element > get the URLS

The following screenshot shows the results of the mentioned steps:

*URL of emojis from YouTube channel ChilledCow:*

[image: URL of emojies from YouTube channel ChilledCow]

Additional note: you can change the size of the emoji - by changing the values in the URL:

Example of emoji - [`:_studynight`](https://yt3.ggpht.com/qKW3_-A6jHFQ5Jqg43ETtH0fdXnxsS8K1YNvz1jlRb9KBa8sRYBEVnucvy54LUU6yWz2kDULLZk=w100-h100-c-k-nd):

```
https://yt3.ggpht.com/qKW3_-A6jHFQ5Jqg43ETtH0fdXnxsS8K1YNvz1jlRb9KBa8sRYBEVnucvy54LUU6yWz2kDULLZk=w100-h100-c-k-nd
```

Change the values of **`w`** and **`h`** from:

> k=w**100**-h**100**-c-k-nd

to:

> k=w**300**-h**300**-c-k-nd

Modified URL - [`:_studynight`](https://yt3.ggpht.com/qKW3_-A6jHFQ5Jqg43ETtH0fdXnxsS8K1YNvz1jlRb9KBa8sRYBEVnucvy54LUU6yWz2kDULLZk=w300-h300-c-k-nd)

Comment: Yes, it seems web scraping is the only option.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a small script to get a list of name / url pairs separated by spaces in the browser console.

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('img[role="option"][class*="emoji"][aria-label^=":"]').values()).slice(0, 20).map(e => e.getAttribute('aria-label') + ' ' + e.getAttribute('src')).join('\n');
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Гариша-Галустян, but this will grab all channel emotes and output them as an object with `code` and `src` attributes.

Additionally, the chat box is in an iframe, which might not have context for `querySelector()` to work correctly.

So, to get an object with all channel emotes:

1. Go to a channel with emotes
2. In the chat box, click the  icon near the input box to load the emoji picker. Wait about a second for all images for the channel to load.
3. Run the full script below. `frameContext()` will ensure that the `querySelector()` is using the correct document base.

```js
let frameContext = function () {
    let frameContext = document.querySelector('ytd-live-chat-frame iframe');

    if (frameContext) {
        frameContext = frameContext.contentDocument.body;
    } else {
        frameContext = document.body;
    }

    return frameContext;
};

Array.from(
    frameContext()
        .querySelector(
            '#categories-wrapper #categories .yt-emoji-picker-renderer'
        )
        .querySelectorAll('img[role="option"][class*="emoji"][aria-label^=":"]')
        .values()
).map((e) => ({ code: e.alt, src: e.src }));
```